# How to check if the record is exist in laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel, select, insert, record

I have a problem, i don't know what's wrong with my code, i try to find out if the data that i will insert to database is exist or not, if not exist i want to insert it. but the problem i can't insert the data even though it's not exist in the database. This is my code:

```
$data_pemohon       = DB::table('data_pemohon')->select('*')->where('noper', $noper)->get();
if(is_null($data_pemohon)){
    $tambah_data_pemohon = DB::table('data_pemohon')->insert($data);
}else{
    echo "the data is exist!";      
}
```

Help me please. Thank you.

Comment: Switch to using models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**->get()** method return collection (even empty), so you have to change it to **->first()** (if not found => return null) or you can check your condition with **if(count($data_pemohon) === 0)** then insert

Answer (score 1):

```
$data_pemohon = DB::table('data_pemohon')->where('noper', $noper)->exists();
if(!$data_pemohon){
    $tambah_data_pemohon = DB::table('data_pemohon')->insert($data);
}else{
    echo "the data is exist!";      
}
```

Comment: The data still can't insert into the database

Comment: how you insert the data can you show how you set your $data variable?

Answer (score 1):

It may be unrelated to your problem but I suggest you use the ['unique' validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique).
A very simple use would be like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'noper' => 'unique:data_pemohon:noper',
]);
if ($validator->fails()) {
    // ... Handle the error
}
// ...Insert your data
```

I recommend reading the documentation to get a good idea about the Laravel's validation process.

Comment: can u give an example with my case?

Comment: This is the example !